# Update multiple div with jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update two div on same page with single jquery .load call

**Script**

```
  $('#ipc').load('/dashboard/details/options');
  $('#inv').load('/dashboard/details/options');
```

I don't want to do this by traditional ajax call.
I also tried append method and .each() function.

Comment: What is your actual problem here, does the code you've shown not work/give an error?  Did you even try the code shown?

Comment: @RobV Problem was with cakephp setup... Now its solved

Comment: How can i achieve this by your way?
$('#ipc').load('/dashboard/details/options #ipc');


  $('#inv').load('/dashboard/details/options #inv');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use comma-separated selectors:

`$('#ipc, #inv').load('/dashboard/details/options');`

Comment: +1 I checked jQuery isn't dumb and makes only one call.

Comment: How can i achieve this by your way?
$('#ipc').load('/dashboard/details/options #ipc');
  $('#inv').load('/dashboard/details/options #inv');

Answer (score 5):

A way to do it :

```
$('#ipc').load('/dashboard/details/options', function(){
    $('#inv').html($('#ipc').html());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.. :)
This works too... Voted up

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#ipc,#ipc2').load('/dashboard/details/options');
```

Comment: How can i achieve this by your way? $('#ipc').load('/dashboard/details/options #ipc'); $('#inv').load('/dashboard/details/options #inv');

Comment: @Deadlock for this purpose i will suggest you to use `get` mehod instead of `load`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
jQuery.load(
    '/dsahboard/details/options',
    {},
    function(res) {
        $('#ipc').html(res);
        $('#inv').html(res);
    }
);
```

Comment: need a selector for `load`, otherwise use `$.get`